# Adding an event to ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event in Android via contact picker

Tags: android, events, android-contacts, contactscontract

In an activity of my Android application, I would like to open the content picker. And when the user selects one of those contacts, there should be a new entry (an event with type "other") that is inserted into the table *ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event*.

Starting the contact picker intent is easy. But then one must get some data for the selected contact and create a new entry in the event table. This is the code I have so far, unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch (requestCode) {  
            case CONTACT_PICKER_ID:  
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            //String contactID = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
            // ADD A NEW BIRTHDAY FOR THE SELECTED CONTACT START
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_OTHER);
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID, 250);
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "2012-12-12");
            Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
            // ADD A NEW BIRTHDAY FOR THE SELECTED CONTACT END
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code requires the permission "WRITE_CONTACTS".

The contact ID "250" is hard-coded. Of course, it should be retrieved from the intent data that is sent along with the contact picker's result.

The code above terminates with a NullPointerException. Why is this so? And how do I get the contact's id from the intent so that I can use it for inserting the new row?

**Edit:** Additionally, the line ...

```
getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

... throws an exception. What's wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it, assuming this is how you called the contact picker:

```
int CONTACT_PICKER_ID = 1001; //some arbitrary number that you choose
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_ID);
```

The data.getData() call returns a lookup key that you have to query the contacts DB for to find the contact's ID.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    switch (requestCode) {  
        case CONTACT_PICKER_ID:  
            Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //get the contact's ID
            contactId = Cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

...
```

The contactId contains the ID you want.

Comment: Thank you! This works fine :) But actually, I need "ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID" instead of "ContactsContract.Contacts._ID". How can I get this column? When I try this with your code, there's an exception because getColumnIndex returns -1.

Comment: I think these IDs are the same. ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID seems to be a reference to ContactsContract.Contacts._ID according to this javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID. The reason why you are getting the error is because CONTACT_ID isn't a column in the row that is returned in the cursor.